# I cannot update my Ubuntu 22.04 server

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

I get ..

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 5.15.0.97.92) but 5.15.0.94.91 is installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 5.15.0.97.92) but 5.15.0.94.91 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try running `apt --fix-broken install`, I get

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
    linux-generic:
      Installed: 5.15.0.97.92
      Candidate: 5.15.0.97.92
      Version table:
     *** 5.15.0.97.92 500
          500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         5.15.0.25.27 500
            500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages

The only thing I can think of is that I added Plex to my server.

     Errors were encountered while processing:
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/0-linux-modules-5.15.0-97-generic_5.15.0-97.107_amd64.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/1-linux-image-5.15.0-97-generic_5.15.0-97.107_amd64.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/2-linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-97-generic_5.15.0-97.107_amd64.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/3-linux-image-generic_5.15.0.97.92_amd64.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/4-linux-headers-5.15.0-97_5.15.0-97.107_all.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/5-linux-headers-5.15.0-97-generic_5.15.0-97.107_amd64.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-GEMHH4/6-linux-headers-generic_5.15.0.97.92_amd64.deb
    needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Ok, so what happens when you do what it says? `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? Paste the results as an *edit* to your question.

Comment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) This is what I get

Comment: Did you notice how @popey asked you to put the results *in an edit to your question*? And give **all** the results.

Comment: Now I see that. Done and Done

Comment: What's the output of `apt policy linux-generic`? Again, put it in your post.

Comment: The outputs you give are not consistent. The first batch says "5.15.0.94.91 is installed" but the apt-policy says "Installed: 5.15.0.97.92" Did you do something between generating these two sets of output?

Comment: Did you try rebooting? Sometimes it magically fixes such issues, but not always

Comment: Did you paste all results; as the message "*E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*" appears to be a summary line from the calling routine, where you should explore up the messages for clues in messages from the subprocess itself. Rather than edit & provide only bits, when unclear the full paste of command & all output would be helpful. If you've provided all, I'd return to basics, knowing your OS/release, do `sudo apt update` & scan all messages for anything not matching what you're running, then `sudo apt full-upgrade` again reading all messages (*not just summary*) etc...

Comment: Try `sudo apt purge dkms ; sudo apt install -f`

Comment: @BradPurgett Please accept an answer instead of putting solutions in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a version conflict between an out-of-tree kernel driver and the kernel version. Frequent causes are VirtualBox and Nvidia drivers, while other no longer necessary drivers for Intel ARC and AMDGPU-PRO may also cause this. The HWE kernel moving to 6.5 from 6.2 may have broken things. If you don't need any out-of-tree drivers, you can remove the entire subsystem for them, which will remove the unneeded drivers, and then the packages will be OK:

```bash
sudo apt purge dkms # Will remove DKMS and any drivers written for DKMS
sudo apt install -f
# Now, if necessary, reinstall any drivers you still need,
# and you will know which driver needs updating
```